# How to calculate a point after rotation given two unit vectors?

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, rotations

I have two unit vectors: before and after rotation.
Point (0, 0, 1) is moved to (-0.42, 0.19, 0.88) after rotation.
If I had a point of (-0.066, 0.635, -0.184) before rotation, how it would be addressed after rotation?

This looked very simple at first, but I am totally stuck here..

Comment: Can you figure out the axis of rotation and angle of rotation? (Hint: use cross product and dot product).

Comment: Um cos(theta) is 0.88. right? theta is 28.36 degrees

Comment: I am not sure after then

Comment: @Nick There’s not enough information here to determine the axis.

Answer (score 1):

There is not enough information. It depends on the axis of rotation. You can, for example, rotate $180^\circ$ around the bisector of the angle formed the original vectors. Or you can rotate around the vector perpendicular to the original two vectors. In fact, you can rotate around any axis in the plane formed by the perpendicular and the angle bisector. The rotation angle is also dependent on the axis

Comment: Oh I see. I think the reason you told there is not enough information is, after Z axis is set from (0, 0, 1) to (-0.42, 0.19, 0.88), the new z axis can rotate to any degree. In this matter, I am assuming that while moving the Z axis, X and Y followed without any further rotation.